# Rootless mode: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375

Tags: docker

I am running docker in **rootless** mode so the `docker.sock` file is in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock`. Where

```
$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/run/user/1000
```

I am trying to run the docker client inside docker. So, I have tried the following command.

```
$ docker run -it -v /run/user/1000/docker.sock:/run/user/1000/docker.sock docker sh
/ # docker run -it ubuntu bash
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The docker daemon is definiely running otherwise it wont be able to run the command. However, i think the docker client within docker container could not connect to the docker daemon which is outside the container.

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here, the solution seems to be

```
docker run -it -v /run/user/1000/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker sh
```

This is because , the docker inside the `docker` image is not rootless. So, their socket is in `/var/run/docker.sock`.